# Query to find duplicate timestamps MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp, duplicates

I have written the following query to find duplicate timestamps within a date range with the intent of then deleting those duplicates with a larger id. However this selection never completes.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    data
WHERE
id NOT IN (SELECT 
        MIN(id)
    FROM
        data
    WHERE
        datapoint_name LIKE 'Temp%'
            AND timestamp BETWEEN '2012-07-31' AND '2012-08-03'
    group by timestamp , datapoint_name)
 AND datapoint_name LIKE 'Temp%'
 AND timestamp BETWEEN '2012-07-31' AND '2012-08-03';
```

I find it strange because the individual components run very fast and there are not that many rows. Specifically:

- the SELECT MIN(ID) ... GROUP BY subquery returns 476 rows in .7 sec.
- the outer SELECT * without id NOT IN() returns 490 rows in 0.001 sec.

In other words there are 14 duplicates, but the NOT IN() operation seems to be taking an exorbitant amount of time. In fact, I've never had the patience to see if it will ever finish. What can I do to speed this up? Have I done something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: how many rows are in this table? Consider that your inner query returns basically one single id, which then has to be compared against every OTHER id in the table. e.g. if there's a million records, you're going to be doing 1,000,000 * 999,999 comparisons with that `not in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably that the subquery is being re-run for each row being compared.  Try moving the subquery to the `from` and using `left join`:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM data d LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT timestamp, datpoint_name, MIN(id) as minid
      FROM data
      WHERE datapoint_name LIKE 'Temp%' AND
            timestamp BETWEEN '2012-07-31' AND '2012-08-03'
     GROUP BY timestamp , datapoint_name
    ) dd
    ON d.datapoint_name = dd.datapoint_name and
       d.timestamp = dd.timestamp and
       d.id = dd.minid
WHERE d.datapoint_name LIKE 'Temp%' AND
      d.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-07-31' AND '2012-08-03' AND
      dd.minid IS NULL;
```

Comment: It'll take me a minute to unpack your answer (I'm fairly new to MySQL), but that worked like a charm.